# double right join query

Tags: sql, sql-server, right-join

i have this table

```
declare @table table(year int, code int, import decimal(5,2))
insert into @table values
(2019,390107,10.00),
(2021,390107,175.00),
(2022,390107,102.00),
(2022,470101,101.00),
(2022,53015101,140.00)
```

i want to make a query that returns the import for each year and for each code contained in the following tables (return import = 0 where there is no record for a specific combination of year and code):

```
declare @years table (year int)
insert into @years values
(2018),
(2019),
(2020),
(2021),
(2022)

declare @codes table (code int)
insert into @codes values
(390107),
(470101),
(470103),
(471103),
(53010101),
(53015101)
```

i tried with somethig like that:

```
select 
    y.year,
    c.code,
    isnull(t.import,0)
from @table t
right join @years y on t.year = y.year
right join @codes c on t.code = c.code
```

the query does not return errors (is not a problem of using create Vs declare, nor a a problem with the tables name). but i don't get the result expected:

**Expected Results**

Having 6 codes and 5 years I expect 30 records (one for each combination of year and code) along with the corresponding `import` value from "@table" for that year/code combination (or 0 if the combination is not found)

| year | code | import |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2018 | 390107 | 0.00 |
| 2018 | 470101 | 0.00 |
| 2018 | 470103 | 0.00 |
| 2018 | 471103 | 0.00 |
| 2018 | 53010101 | 0.00 |
| 2018 | 53015101 | 0.00 |
| 2019 | 390107 | 10.00 |
| 2019 | 470101 | 0.00 |
| 2019 | 470103 | 0.00 |
| 2019 | 471103 | 0.00 |
| 2019 | 53010101 | 0.00 |
| 2019 | 53015101 | 0.00 |
| 2020 | 390107 | 0.00 |
| 2020 | 470101 | 0.00 |
| 2020 | 470103 | 0.00 |
| 2020 | 471103 | 0.00 |
| 2020 | 53010101 | 0.00 |
| 2020 | 53015101 | 0.00 |
| 2021 | 390107 | 175.00 |
| 2021 | 470101 | 0.00 |
| 2021 | 470103 | 0.00 |
| 2021 | 471103 | 0.00 |
| 2021 | 53010101 | 0.00 |
| 2021 | 53015101 | 0.00 |
| 2022 | 390107 | 102.00 |
| 2022 | 470101 | 101.00 |
| 2022 | 470103 | 0.00 |
| 2022 | 471103 | 0.00 |
| 2022 | 53010101 | 0.00 |
| 2022 | 53015101 | 140.00 |

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Your query returns a result set ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=53095c752a453381aee267ef41559096)), so why isn't it "working"?

Comment: It fails only when the declaration happen separately, so that the query won't recognize the variables initialized before. In fact putting the creation statements into different cells of the fiddle will fire the error (which OP may be referring to). This problem won't happen for table creation statements (since they have a side-effect on the database). @Larnu

Comment: That's standard for variables, @lemon , that they persist only in the scope and batch they are created. "Not working" could literally be *anything* here, from Getting an error, getting unexpected results, causing a crash, causes the OP's cat to vomit... I would suggest that the value the IOP has used **table** *variables* to provide sample data is likely irrelevant. If, however, they are misunderstanding the scope of persistence of variables, there are plenty of duplicates out there on that.

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Debug questions require a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help]

Comment: When you get a result you don't expect, say what you expect & why you expect it, justified by reference to authoritative documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) Otherwise you're just asking us to rewrite yet another definition & presentation for you to misunderstand, with no idea what your misconceptions are. [mre] [ask] Plus for basic problems those will be faqs you can then characterize specifically enough to (re)search & find. Please use standard punctuation & spelling. Please remove/flag obsolete comments.

Comment: That is not "minimal" representative data. PS It is usually helpful  to sort output on all columns or it is difficult to compare to alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cross join the Codes and Years to get every combination and then use that in the outer join

```
SELECT Y.year,
       C.code,
       ISNULL(T.import, 0) AS import
FROM   @years Y
       CROSS JOIN @codes C
       LEFT JOIN @table T
              ON T.year = Y.year
                 AND T.code = C.code
```